# Python check_output not working correctly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a shell script that executes a C binary with an arg that is passed to it. When I run the shell script manually, everything works as expected, every time.

When I try to do it through check_output, sometimes it works, but most of the time it fails with strange results.

The python that runs the check_output

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def getWaterTemp():
    return 4.06

def getPH():
    temp=getWaterTemp()
    ph = subprocess.check_output(["./getPH.sh", str(temp)])
    ph = float(ph[1:5])
    if ph>0.0:
        return ph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print getPH()
```

The getPH.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ph=$(/home/pi/GrowControlBox/phtempset1.1 T,$1)
echo "$ph"
```

When I run the shell script it returns a value as such:

```
"'8.66'"
```

When I run the python, sometimes it returns the value, sometimes it returns:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ?▒▒▒
```

Also, every now and then when running the python, it will return a value, but will not set the temperature for the sensor. (This happens in the C binary) Sometimes, I have to run it multiple times for it to set the temperature that was passed. But when running the shell script, it will set the temp, and return
the expected value, every time.

Here is another random error that I get when running the python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 42, in <module>
    print getPH()
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 36, in getPH
    ph = float(ph[1:5])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Proof that the shell script works on its own, along with a different C binary to check that the temp was set correctly from previous shell script run:

```
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 17.0
8.697
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 2.5
8.788
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 6.8
8.758
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 9.1
8.746
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ~/phtemp t
t
Reading: 1
Reading: 63
Reading: 84
Reading: 172
Reading: 57
Reading: 46
Reading: 48
Reading: 57
Reading: 0
Reading: 0
?T▒9.09
Status: 1
Reading: 1
Reading: 56
Reading: 46
Reading: 55
Reading: 52
Reading: 52
Reading: 0
Reading: 0
Reading: 0
Reading: 0
8.744
```

Comment: You might find [this StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) helpful in the future, also.

Comment: I am active there, but as this really pertains more to just python, i figured it would be best to post in the regular stack overflow

Comment: What is the purpose of `ph[1:5]`? What *should* it return?

Comment: strip the ' from the front and format to 4 characters (including .)


`8.66`

Comment: You can't convert string to float... so what is the string when it fails?

Comment: Multiple things. it has been null, '', it has been ?▒▒▒, it has been 8.66 and worked.

Comment: Yes, you can. `float('8.66')` returns 8.66 as a float object. @tdelaney

Comment: @zachgates - the ValueError says you can't convert the string to a float... Its not that you can't convert any strings.... its that you can't convert that string. Suppose it was a text message explaining why a float wasn't returned?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to convert pieces of a string to a float. Assuming that the format of `ph` is `"'8.66'"` with any number of decimal places, try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def getWaterTemp():
    return 4.06

def getPH():
    temp = getWaterTemp()
    ph = subprocess.check_output(["./getPH.sh", str(temp)])
    ph = float(ph[1:-1]) # exclude quotations
    if ph > 0.0:
        return ph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getPH())
```

Comment: That for sure will fail. The entire reason for ph[1:5] is to remove the ' at the front of the ph string, which will cause the ValueError

Comment: Is the string returned `"'8.66'"`? @jslay

Comment: correct, i meant it as literal when saying '8.66', I guess the way you write it is better understood, sorry.

Comment: I've made an edit. It should now work correctly. @jslay

Comment: On one occasion:

`8.15`

On another:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 42, in <module>
    print getPH()
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 36, in getPH
    ph = float(ph[1:-1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
`

Comment: I promise the sh script, when run by itself from the shell, works every single time. This is why I am so confused as to what is going on here.

Comment: `pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 17.0
8.697
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 2.5
8.788
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 6.8
8.758
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./getPH.sh 9.1
8.746
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ~/phtemp t
?T▒9.09
8.744
pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $
`

Comment: Add the line `print(ph)` before `ph = float(ph[1:-1])`, and post what happens.

Comment: off topic, how do i break line in comments?

Comment: I get nulls, '', which is where check_output isnt operating properly


`pi@jslayrpi ~/GrowControlBox $ ./GrowControlBox.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 43, in <module>
    print getPH()
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 37, in getPH
    ph = float(ph[1:-1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
`

Comment: Did you try my original solution? `ph = float(ph)` @jslay

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 43, in <module>
    print getPH()
  File "./GrowControlBox.py", line 37, in getPH
    ph = float(ph)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Also, see original post for real output of getPH.sh

Comment: I just noticed if I run the python script back to back really fast, it will work. Any ideas?

Comment: from what I can tell, it appears to not be passing the arguments correctly from check_output

Comment: For some reason, when the check_output is run, the c program fails, but when i run the sh script from shell, as it works. does check_output wrap the arguments in something?